# How to add a trend line in a pivot table?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have made a Python program that receives an Excel input file with the following structure:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| start date  | hour | sector | KPI_1  |KPI_2 | KPI_3 | KPI_4 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
 01-01-2016      0    AUX_534    89.10    87.2    84.9    90.12
 01-01-2016      0    BVX_234    12.92    67.2    74.9    50.50
 01-01-2016      1    AUX_534    53.26    57.1    24.20   40.43
 01-01-2016      1    BVX_234    90.95    12.0    74.45   50.76
 01-01-2016      2    AUX_534    63.21    76.1    34.1    23.34
 01-01-2016      2    BVX_234    86.90    57.4    64.4    40.98
```

Then my program does the following to generate this Excel output file in a pivot table with 4 sheets (the 4 kpis):

```
sheet_1_KPI_1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
hour      |        0   |    1  |    2   |   3   |   4   | .....  23 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
sector    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------         
AUX_534   |      89.10 | 53.26 | 63.21  | ...   | ... |  ..... | ... |
BVX_234   |      12.92 | 90.95 | 86.90  | ...   | ... |  ..... | ... |


sheet_2_KPI_2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
hour      |        0   |    1  |    2   |   3   |   4   | .....  23 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
sector    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------         
AUX_534   |      87.2 | 57.1 | 76.1  | ...   | ... |  ..... | ... |
BVX_234   |      67.2 | 12.0 | 57.4  | ...   | ... |  ..... | ... |

sheet_3_KPI_3 ....
sheet_4_KPI_4 ....
```

This is the code I used to generate the described pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

#input 
working_excel_file_2G = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\dev\\CO_N_Hourly_01_01_2016.xlsx")
#output
writer_to_Excel = ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\dev\\temp\\Hourly_Analysis_CO.xlsx")

hourly_data = working_excel_file.parse("Sheet-2")

pivot_table_kpi_1 = pd.pivot_table(hourly_data,index=["sector"],values=["KPI_1"], columns=["hour"])
pivot_table_kpi_2 = pd.pivot_table(hourly_data,index=["sector"],values=["KPI_2"], columns=["hour"])
pivot_table_kpi_3 = pd.pivot_table(hourly_data,index=["sector"],values=["KPI_3"], columns=["hour"])
pivot_table_kpi_4 = pd.pivot_table(hourly_data,index=["sector"],values=["KPI_4"], columns=["hour"])

print("Writing the dataframe to an Excel file")
pivot_table_kpi_1.to_excel(writer_to_Excel, "KPI_1")
pivot_table_kpi_2.to_excel(writer_to_Excel, "KPI_2")
pivot_table_kpi_3.to_excel(writer_to_Excel, "KPI_3")
pivot_table_kpi_4.to_excel(writer_to_Excel, "KPI_4")
writer_to_Excel.save()
```

I want to add a trend line at the end of column 23 to make a visualization of the behavior of each row of data, that is, something like the following picture:

[image: Trending line that I generated with Excel]

I do not know how to draw this trend line with pandas or with other library that can do the same as shown in the picture.

Suggestions and improvements to my "tables" are well received.

Comment: This is something you do in Excel with a feature called sparklines. This is not what pandas is meant for.

Comment: do you know if there is any other alternative besides using Pandas or opening the output excel file and adding the trending line manually?

Comment: I'm not sure perhaps someone else will have greater insight into this.

Comment: Read about [OpenPyXL: Charts](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/introduction.html)